# How to call the argument name of a constructor inside a new function?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pass-by-reference, decision-tree

A DecisionTreeRegressor has the callable arguments of max_depth, min_samples_split, and so on. I want to create a function that chooses which argument (feature of the tree) to call. An example:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor

x = some data
y = some data

def tryfeatures(feature, value, x, y):
    tree = DecisionTreeRegressor(feature=value)
    return tree.fit(x, y)

tryfeatures('max_depth', 5, x, y)
```

Here, I am selecting 'max_depth' as the feature, and I cannot find the way of expressing to the constructor DecisionTreeRegressor that I am going to be defining the feature max_depth as the value 5.
This is what I would like the DecisionTreeRegressor to do after that piece of code:

```
tree = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=5)
```

Then, I would do

```
tryfeatures('min_samples_split', 3, x, y)
```

and so on. I am not sure if this is referred as pass by reference or if it has to do with kwargs, either way, I need your help.

I was expecting the decision tree to be fitted with the parameter that I gave (max_depth), and the value of it, but I know that that was not the way of calling it.

Comment: `DTR(feature=value)` passes a parameter literally named `feature`; having a variable of the same name doesn't magically make that code do something entirely different.  One way of doing this would be `DTR(**{feature: value})`.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass a dictionary where each key match with the argument name and each value with the corresponding value, you can use this strategy for any function (in particular constructor). Example:

```
def my_funct(a, b, c):
  # do somthing here 
  return a+b+c

# this is valid 

args = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3 }
result = my_funct(**args) # result == 6
```

Note you need to ensure to pass mandatory arguments, optional ones can be present or not

In your case:

```
def tryfeatures(args_for_dtr, x, y):
    tree = DecisionTreeRegressor(**args_for_dtr)
    return tree.fit(x, y)

tryfeatures({'max_depth':5}, x, y)
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly. Just learned something new about kwargs.